# Why am I not getting any results for my simulation?

Tags: abaqus, finite-element-analysis

I've been trying to run a dynamic/explicit simulation of the response of a small building under a combination of stresses to a scenario where a supporting column is suddenly lost.

However, when the simulation completed I did not get any stresses or deformations in the results.I applied the dead load and live load of 2,500Pa to each floor, however in the results I am not getting any reactions or stress distributions in the model at all.

What might be the problem?
I am still quite new to the Abaqus, so I might be missing something obvious. 
Thank you

Comment: Did you define FieldOutput request?

Comment: There are simply too many possible issues to meaningfully answer this.

Answer (score 0):

One guess could be your loading magnitude. Increase your loading to see if your problem remain or not!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have created a field output

in CAE

- select the "Step" Module
- click the "Create Field Output" button

this allows you to select the outputs you want to view from your analysis
I would guess you require displacements and stresses